# Javascript: Reset a counter if an image does not exist?

Tags: javascript, image, loops, error-handling, counter

I've made a javascript function to display a number of images in a folder one after another. I'd like to automatically reset my counter if the next image doesn't exist. Eliminating the necessity of passing the number of images in a folder to the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Slideshow</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</html>

<body>

  <div id="output" class="slides"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var pageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var pic_info = pageURL.split('?');
    var pic_path = pic_info[0] + '/';
    var pic_max_number = 3;
    var pic_number = 0;

    pic_slideshow();

    function pic_slideshow() {
      pic_number++;

      if (pic_number > pic_max_number) {
          pic_number = 1
         }

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<img src="' + pic_path + pic_number + '.jpg">';

      setTimeout(pic_slideshow, 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds
    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'D like to add an error handling function, that resets the pic_number variable to 1 to restart the loop. Any ideas using pure javascript?
Thanks...

Comment: You're splitting on the query string in the URL. why not use the built-in object? `location.search`

Comment: Well, it worked - just to get the path to the folder containing the images. I'm rewriting the div object with the current image number from the loop...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) attribute of the image tag to reset the global variable `pic_number` to 1, and load image `1.jpg` in place of the missing image.

Change your `innerHTML` value to:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
  '<img src="' + pic_path + pic_number + '.jpg"'
  + ' onerror="pic_number=1; this.src=\'' + pic_path + '1.jpg\'">';
```

---

If you add an event listener in your Javascript code you'll need to modify how you're updating your pics.

In your HTML add an `img` tag:

```
<div id="output" class="slides"><img src=""></div>
```

And in your `script` body add the `onerror` event listener to that `img` element:

```
document.querySelector('#output img').onerror = function (evt) {
  pic_number = 1;
  evt.target.src = pic_path + '1.jpg';
}
```

And in your `pic_slideshow` function change the `src` value of the existing image element rather than creating a new one:

```
document.querySelector('#output img').src = pic_path + pic_number + '.jpg';
```

An event listener will get lost each time you change the `#output` div `innerHTML`.

---

Alternatively you can use the `addEventListener` method:

```
document.querySelector('#output img').addEventListener('error', function (evt) {
  pic_number = 1;
  evt.target.src = pic_path + '1.jpg';
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked a treat! Just changing the  innerHTML. So simple...

Answer (score 0):

You could sense onerror in the img element, or add an eventlistener via JavaScript and reset the counter.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)